# fixed Element gets unvisible on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I developed a sidebar. However I have a issue that the button required to open the sidebar gets invisible on mobile devices. If you know the position you can click on it and it works. The button to hide it works fine.

Here is a link to the website:

https://gdi.ethz.ch/jenkins/pages/current.html

And here the relevant html:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container container-fluid col-md-12">
    <header><nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"></a>
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
       Some menue
    </ul>
</nav>

</header>
    <div id="main">
        the site content  
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

And the css code:

```
#menu-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1100;
    background-color: #009bf0;
    color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 249px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #menu-toggle {
    left: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}



#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #009bf0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `<a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle"></a>` was inside the fixed `#sidebar-wrapper`. This resulted in an issue in chrome mobile. By moving the `#menu-toggle` outside the `#sidebar-wrapper` everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is in a fixed position it is getting cut off when your screen gets smaller on mobile.

You'll either need to adjust how it handles the viewport or have its width adjust with the screen.

Comment: The element is still in the visible region. You can actually click on it. However it is not visible. So it is not outside the screen.